# Does an add/remove role require a "Publish to PDP" action to take effect in wso2?

Tags: xacml, wso2-identity-server

For testing purposes, We set a given policy that allows GET operations on one resource to users with Manager Role.

Then we used the "PEP TryIt" form to check how the policy was applied to users with and without the Manager role, and right after removing and adding the role. We found these two behaviors:
1) The PEP TryIt, returns Permit, for a given user who got his/her Manager **role removed** => Unexpected.
Only after publishing the given policy to the PDP, the system returns NotApplicable.

2) The PEP TryIt, returns NotApplicable, for a given user who got his/her Manager **role reassigned** => Unexpected 
Only after publishing the given policy to the PDP, the system returns Permit.

Does the policy need to be published to the PDP, every time a Role is granted/removed to a given User ? Is this the expected behavior or should be considered a bug ?

Thanks!
Fermin Ordaz.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. I guess you have experienced the correct behavior.....

Carbon user store is acts an attribute finder (PIP) for the PDP. Basically Carbon user store is the default PIP implementation. In the PIP level, PDP has introduced the attribute caching. In simply, we can say that It caches the user's attribute (here user's roles). Your assignment modification, It is not known by the PIP cache. (As User store and PDP act as two separate entities) Therefore it can not invalidate the cache. That has been caused to experience above result. Basically Attribute sources (user stores or any ) are independent from the PDP and they can be running in separately. There are two way you can void this,

1. Once you update any attributes that is related to PIP. you can clear the attribute cache using UI or API. In UI, you can go to `Entitlement-> PDP->Extension` and There is icon to clear attribute cache.  This has been expose via admin service..  therefore you can call this method from some external application as well.
2. You can disable or reduce the invalidation value of the attribute cache using `entitlement.properties` file which can be found at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/security` directory

> PDP.AttributeCaching.Enable=true
>
> PDP.AttributeCaching.CachingInterval=300

Also,  for `NotApplicable`, I guess you have not enable the policy in PDP.. Once you have publish a policy to PDP..  It must be enabled to put it in to actual runtime